# PM2 Heroku Deployment fails to launch application

Tags: node.js, heroku, pm2

I am following the directions here: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/use-pm2-with-cloud-providers/

Attempting to push a test app to Heroku and getting the error message:

```java
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/app/.pm2
 2017-12-04T22:35:51.928946+00:00 app[web.1]: [PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
 2017-12-04T22:35:51.955730+00:00 app[web.1]: [PM2][ERROR] script not found : /app/dist/server.js
 2017-12-04T22:35:51.955882+00:00 app[web.1]: script not found : /app/dist/server.js
```

My package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm install pm2 -g",
  "start": "pm2 start ./dist/server.js -i 1 --attach"
}
```

This is the folder structure:
[image]

I am able to launch this locally by `npm start`. Any ideas or clues why this is happening?

Comment: What method are you using to deploy?

Comment: git push heroku master. Using first deployment method of pm2

Comment: Is it possible your dist folder is being ignored in the push? What is in .gitignore?

Comment: I’ll take a look when I get back home. Thanks!

Comment: @posit labs I had the dist folder in the gitignore! You solved it! Thank you soooo much. How can i give you credit for your help?

Comment: Glad I could help! I've submitted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your dist folder is being pushed to git. Check the contents of .gitignore.